# Can't read appsettings.json without DI due to missing Configuration Builder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings, .net-core-2.0

I'm trying to read from *appsettings.json* and I don't want to use DI. I simply wish to access the file. I'm following [simple configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#simple-configuration) as suggested by MS.

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

class Program
{
  public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    Configuration = builder.Build();
  }
}
```

The classes get from red highlight to green when I specify the reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` except for one - the `Configuration Builder` instance creation. It produces the following error.

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

All the examples I've found are set up the same way. Even the [docs for `Configuration Builder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder) say that it's supopsed to be there. I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

I'm using .NET Core 2.0 if it's of any significance.

Comment: that is weird, I created the same console app and it's no problem. You create a new empty .net Core 2.0 console app?

Comment: Did you add the correct package? w/o the ASP.NET Core Meta package you need to reference the stuff yourself. P.S. question is totally unrelated to DI, as the configuration never required it in the first place and the new keyword was used, even in ASP:NET Core

Comment: @kloarubeek I can't explain it, neither. Can you confirm that there's the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` installed? I'm curious because when I installed it ([like this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/)), as suggested in the answer below, I got it to work. Please check the *Dependecies/NuGet* in *Solution Explorer* (it doesn't show in my *NuGet Solution Explorer* for some reason).

Comment: @Tseng I might have fallen victim to MS helping me project template making me unaware that I needed some stuff. Glad to discover that, thanks. What package is it precisely that you suggest that `ConfigurationBuilder` in in? I would expect it to be in the same as `IConfigurationBuilder` and that, as I mention in my question, **did** work.

Comment: Yes, I only left Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json so it's probably related to the .AddJsonFile that it was missing.

Comment: When you are looking for a package which contains a specific class and/or extension method, use Microsoft/.NET Core Team's [Reverse Package Search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) to search for it. i.e. http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=AddJsonFile

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`AddJsonFile`  method is in the  **`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`** package and in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` namespace.

So [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/) package need to be added to project.Once all the packages are restored successfully it works perfectly.
If you have already added them another error might be blocking the build before that point gets compiled.

Comment: this did work for me -- but I had an older project which worked _without_ installing the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`.  weird.

Answer (score 2):

I had something similar.
I already had ConfigurationBuilder referenced and working in another project of the same solution.

I copy/pasted the ConfigurationBuilder code to a new project and got the same problem as you.

I looked at NuGet installed packages for the solution.

Sure enough, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json was installed for the working project but not the new one.

Installed it for the new project and voilà.